# Pandas Find distance amoung the group

Tags: python, pandas

Given data set contains,

> Brand | Sector|Year|Price|Sales.

> B1, S1, 2023, 45900, 400

> B1, S1, 2022, 45000, 500

> B2, S1, 2022, 45400, 520

The Group may be defined as Same Brand and Sector, and the distance may be defined as change in Price by Change in Sale and with in a group. Lets say there are 4 (A,B,C,D) members for Brand B1 and Sector S1, each member having its own Count of Sales, and Price. We can form 6 Pairs,
AB, AC,AD,BC,BD,CD and from each pair we could find Change is Price by Change in Sales.
(A.Price - B.Price ) / (A.Sale - B.Sale )

Tried things like df.diff(), df.roll() etc. But that can compare only one element next to another.

Comment: Please add a more complete data set (showing the members that you talk about) and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typical that when you want pair-wise calculation within a group, you want to merge on the key, here `Brand` and `Sector`. Then what you need is just a straightforward calculation:

```
(df.merge(df, on=['Brand','Sector'])
   .query('Year_x != Year_y')
   .assign(Change=lambda x: x['Price_x'].sub(x['Price_y']).div(x['Sales_x']-x['Sales_y']))
)
```

Output:

```
  Brand Sector  Year_x  Price_x  Sales_x  Year_y  Price_y  Sales_y  Change
1    B1     S1    2023    45900      400    2022    45000      500    -9.0
2    B1     S1    2022    45000      500    2023    45900      400    -9.0
```

Comment: Should it be 'Year_x < Year_y' , to avoid Duplication, Like AB calculation is same as BA ?

Comment: Yes, but in the question you requested 6 pairs, not 3 pairs...

Comment: Yes, A, B, C, D, taken 2 at a time without order we get 6 pairs, AB, AC,AD, BC,BD,CD , Couting BA, CA  etc will create a kind of duplicate. Anyways I think 'Year_x < Year_y' would help to solve